# trac: custom ticket state not visible in timeline

Tags: trac, timeline

I am using AdvancedTicketWorkflowPlugin 0.10dev and I have created my own ticket state (claimed_fixed). Everything seems to work, but changes about claiming fixed are not visible in the timeline. I checked timeline section in trac.ini, but haven't found and place I need to change. What I have to do, to make it visible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting

```
[timeline]
ticket_show_details = true
```

in your trac.ini, then on the timeline page click the "Ticket updates" checkbox and the "Update" button.